# which centos image can I use on aws with vagrant?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, vagrant, centos6

When I configure vagrant with aws plugin to use a centos image, I get the following error message:

`sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`.

read somewhere that this means user is prompted for password when doing a sudo command.

but that is weird because the username for this machine is root..

How can I resolve this?

Comment: can you post the `sudo` command line?

Comment: I don't have a sudo command. I believe it is something internal in vagrant. I get `mkdir -p /vagrant` on the console. but there's no sudo in that command.

Comment: `Defaults requiretty` is a default for sudo so you have to have an controlling terminal, and it has been deemed useless and will be removed someday. So you can remove that line using visudo.  Source: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password

Comment: @VernBurton Do you want to answer the question and I will mark you as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Defaults requiretty` is a default for sudo so you have to have an controlling terminal, and it has been deemed useless and will be removed someday. So you can remove that line using visudo.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password